# Simple jquery slide fix i cannot figure out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have text that slides from right to left and such. I cant for the life of me figure this out. Basically i want text to show up and only when pages loads and refreshed and when a link is clicked that text slides off and new text slides on ect. I

http://jsfiddle.net/XAyL3/

Comment: So what is wrong currently?

Comment: basically i want text to be there before i click show/hide then new text shows up that is hidden

Comment: All 3 links should be shown at the start, OR just first (the rest should be hidden)?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/XAyL3/2/

Comment: like it needs to be like this "first text" (when page loads)    then you click first button and "second text" loads

Comment: It's still unclear what your desired result is. Can you outline the events would be in a list, i.e.

- page loads, first hidden text is visible under first link
- user clicks first link
- first row of text slides right
- new line of text slides in from right

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have some of the text scroll in automatically once the page is loaded, try using

```
$(document).load
```

to fire your function to scroll in the text!

I hope this is a step in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the JS

```
$('.hidden:first').animate({"left": "0"}, "slow");
```

Comment: like it needs to be like this "first text" (when page loads) then you click first button and "second text" loads